# How to remove blur effect on hover of TabBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using a TabBar and on hover, it's showing the blur effect. Please see the below before hover and after hover images :

[image: Before hover]

[image: After hover]

I have not given any extra property to add any effect.
Please check the code below:

```
  RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 1,
            child: Material(
              color:  Color(0XFFEFEFEF),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                child: TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      color: primaryColor),
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: <Widget>[
                    RotatedBox(
                     quarterTurns: -1,
                      child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        icon: Icon(
                        Icons.assignment_outlined,
                      ),
                      text: Text(
                        "Timesheet",
                      ),],

                       ),
                       ),
                     RotatedBox(
                     quarterTurns: -1,
                      child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        icon: Icon(
                        Icons.settings_sharp,
                      ),
                      text: Text(
                        "Settings",
                      ),],

                       ),
                       ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you but I don't clear what exactly you want

Comment: I don't want the blur effect on hover of tabbar